# How to edit autogenerated comment template on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

How to edit template of Xcode generated comment on top of every file?

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  project1
//
//  Created by sdsfsdf on 05/08/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 fgdfg. All rights reserved.
//
```

Comment: Why you want to edit this?

Comment: You can edit or remove the comment. it has no effect in your code.

Comment: @Sivagami i want to provide custom name on autogeneration of comment . i dont want name set on mac  displayed on comment

Comment: @Sivagami@luckyShubra i dont want to edit name manually on creating new file

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify anything under the `/Developer` hierarchy.

Instead, clone the templates you want to have customized variants of. Then change their names and the information in them. Finally, put them in the appropriate location in your account's `Library/Application Support` folder, specifically:

- File templates: `~/Library/Application
  Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/File Templates/`
- Target templates: `~/Library/Application
  Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Target Templates/`
- Project templates: `~/Library/Application
  Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/`

That way they won't be overwritten when you install new developer tools.